# Unable to access jarfile SignApk

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to sign an APK with [SignApk](https://code.google.com/p/signapk/), but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile signapk.jar
```

I have appended my JDK directory as well as my SignAPK directory to my system path variable. The java command works fine through the command-line, but I can't seem to get the -jar option to work correctly for signing APKs.

My SignApk folder is located on my C:\ drive, so it looks like this:
[image]

Here is what I am trying to do through the command-line:
[image]

Please ignore the blank space in between the variables as I was trying to cover up my details. The syntax that I am using is:

```
java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 myapk.apk myapk-signed.apk
```

I have tried the commands from the SignApk directory as well as the bin directory inside of that directory. Can anyone help me troubleshoot how to resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use IDE tool for signing your apk? Just left click on project, export, android application. If you realy need to sign it from comand line - try close eclipse before. It seems like your apk file is locked by some other process.

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do is modify an existing APK, so I'm unfamiliar with how to import an existing APK into Eclipse in order to sign it. I'm also unsure of what might be locking down the APK file since it is not being used by any other processes when I try to run the command.

Answer (score 10):

As you might notice, there is no **signapk.jar** file there, there is only **signapk** without extension.

Download different SignApk from here:

```
http://www.mediafire.com/download/h5fob1afzt1p4ss/SignApk.rar
Password: SanketN8
```

Answer (score 5):

just download Signapk.zip and unzip wherever you wish, paste your apk inside the signapk folder.

open cmd / terminal , change directory to signapk

`java -jar signapk.jar testkey.x509.pem testkey.pk8 test.apk test-signed.apk`

copy and replace with you existing file name (test.apk) and output file (test-signed.apk )

signapk.zip - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByAytNiwJoUaQ3NvVzlPX0xGUFU

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TyXE.png)

Answer (score 0):

In case one encounters this message when signing a LineageOS build:
Get rid of `./build/tools/releasetools/` prepended to (old) commands used for signing.
See [https://wiki.lineageos.org/signing_builds#:~:text=For%20LineageOS%20versions-,older%20than,-18.1%20you%20will](https://wiki.lineageos.org/signing_builds#:%7E:text=For%20LineageOS%20versions-,older%20than,-18.1%20you%20will)